# QML- Right Click Not Detected in MouseArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm working on an image editor and specifically working on setting the current left or right button's associated color using a MouseArea (inside a Button type). The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to filter for particular buttons at all. Here's the snippet giving me trouble:

```
    Button {
        x: 60
        width: 80
        height: 40
        text: "Blue"

        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        onButtonClick: {
            if(mouseArea.pressedButtons & Qt.RightButton) {
                console.log("Right button used");
                GlobalState.setRightColorValues(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            } else {
                console.log("Left button used");
                GlobalState.setLeftColorValues(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            }
        }
    }
```

(If needed I can provide the entirety of Button.qml, but it's mostly from [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/gettingstartedqml.html)).

I'm trying to follow the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-mousearea.html), but the method used to filter for right mouse clicks doesn't seem to work (anymore, anyway). What happens is the statement "defaults" to assuming a left click. I've also tried separating the two into different if-statements, but doing so causes *no* buttons to be filtered explicitly.

What needs to be changed in order to filter for specific mouse buttons? Or will I have to implement the sort of "switch primary color" button used in Paint/Paint.NET?

Edit 1: I've realized that there was a relevant snippet missing from Button.qml-

```
 MouseArea{
    id: buttonMouseArea;

    acceptedButtons: Qt.AllButtons;
    hoverEnabled: true

    onEntered: parent.color = onHoverColor
    onExited:  parent.color = buttonColor

    anchors.fill: parent;

    onClicked: buttonClick();
}
```

This is nested inside a `Rectangle`, which also holds a `Text` field.

Answer (score 30):

By default MouseArea only handles the left mouse button. You can handle other buttons by setting the acceptedButtons property. You can determine which button caused the click by using the `mouse` MouseEvent that is accessible in the onClicked handler.

```
MouseArea {
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

    onClicked: {
        if (mouse.button === Qt.RightButton) { // 'mouse' is a MouseEvent argument passed into the onClicked signal handler
            console.log("right button clicked!")
        } else if (mouse.button === Qt.LeftButton) {
            console.log("left button clicked!")
        }
    }
}
```

See [acceptedButtons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#acceptedButtons-prop), and `mouse` [MouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html)

Comment: Actually, I've enabled all buttons in Button.qml- I should probably post that snippet. I'll edit my main post to emphasize that.

Answer (score 19):

You can check the button this way:

```
MouseArea {
   acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
   onClicked: {
        if(mouse.button & Qt.RightButton) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using `if` statements if you dedicate a `MouseArea` for each mouse button you're interested in:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "#ffe"
        border.color: "grey"
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height / 2
        Text {
            id: txt
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Use Mouse here"
        }
        MouseArea {
           anchors.fill: parent
           onClicked: txt.text = "left click detected";
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
            onClicked: txt.text = "right click detected";
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACbHicjVHBSsQwEL33K4buPYLHLh50Tx4Ed9EPiMm0CWaTMp3iivTfTVoaN6DUdwh584Z5LxN77gMxHPk4WvVe2YKKQ/BMwQ3Vs+wQviqIOKFi6Tu38gTplQk0CIWekR59A72keM8NKrhADdS7tsU6V98CaSSxih3h54/4YTWbdZCYGdzAbdYN2s5wblho0fGCF74KmWB1A3zhorYZPoHjrBjxdUB4CmM8DdLVS6Z8m9V7Qlk6ryatde43g+APLm4cl3wi2cEd1A5bBpUU0Mhx86jr/f9dN21BKoV9nPowMgc/NPHrxSltcikUvX9kpHnxGyGnaqq+AZxorSc=)

Answer (score 1):

What I have observed is that `pressedButtons` works only with `onPressed`, not with `onClicked`.
I find that kind of odd, because `clicked()` is nothing but [a press followed by a release](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#clicked-signal). Hence I assumed that it will work with `clicked()` as well, but sadly it doesn't.

Example:

```
MouseArea {
    id: idMouseArea

    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

    anchors.fill: parent

    //onClicked: {   // pressedButtons not identified with onClicked
    onPressed: {     // pressedButtons identified and works well with onPressed
        if (idMouseArea.pressedButtons & Qt.RightButton) {
            console.log("right-button pressed")
        } else if (idMouseArea.pressedButtons & Qt.LeftButton) {
            console.log("left-button pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have observed with Qt 5.5.1 and QtQuick 2.5. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#pressedButtons-prop) doesn't show how to use `pressedButtons` property with if-else. Please correct/comment if the observation is wrong.

---

**Update:**
If you direly need to use `pressedButtons` with `onClicked` you can use following hack to do so.

```
    MouseArea {
        property int mouseButtonClicked: Qt.NoButton

        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton | Qt.LeftButton

        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            if (pressedButtons & Qt.LeftButton) {
                mouseButtonClicked = Qt.LeftButton
            } else if (pressedButtons & Qt.RightButton) {
                mouseButtonClicked = Qt.RightButton
            }
        }

        onClicked: {
            if (mouseButtonClicked === Qt.LeftButton) {
                console.log("left button clicked")
            } else if (mouseButtonClicked === Qt.RightButton) {
                console.log("right button clicked")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it was different back then but `onClicked` receives an arg `mouse` which has a property `button` that contains which button is clicked. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#clicked-signal)

Comment: `pressedButtons` contains which buttons are currently pressed. the reason `pressedButtons` does not work with `onClicked` is because `onClicked` occurs only after the mouse button has been released, which means no buttons are currently pressed. @StefanFabian is correct, the `mouse` event should be used instead.